# jQuery Ui Dialog doesnt show up

Tags: jquery, dialog

I have a div container that is initially hidden when the page loads. Inside that div I have a container that has my dialog content:

```
<div style="display:none;" id="dialog-container">
    content
</div>
```

The problem I have is that when the user clicks a link to open the dialog:

```
jQuery("#dialog-link").click(function() {

    //shows modal box

    jQuery( "#dialog-container" ).dialog({
        width:"820",
        resizable: false, 
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            Ok: function() {
                jQuery( this ).dialog( "close" );
            }
        }
    });

});//close click
```

the overlay shows up but the dialog itself is no where to be seen. What am I doing wrong? Is the fact that the div is initially hidden has something to do with it?

Thanks.

**UPDATE**

I found the problem but still don't have a solution. The .ui-dialog class has a 'top' property that is way too high and so the dialog opens way off the screen.

Comment: There might be a difference between jquery-ui versions 1.8.18: http://jsfiddle.net/SAYT8/ vs. 1.9.2: http://jsfiddle.net/5CCxh/ Using 1.9.2 dialog shows up, but not with 1.8.18

Comment: that's strange I am using version 1.9.2

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you show the dialog container to remove `display:none`

```
jQuery("#dialog-link").click(function() {


//shows modal box

  jQuery( "#dialog-container" ).dialog({
     width:"820",
     resizable: false, 
     modal: true,
     buttons: {
        Ok: function() {
          jQuery( this ).dialog( "close" );
        }
     }
   });

   jQuery( "#dialog-container" ).show(); //make visible
});
```

Working Example: http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Still doesn't work for some reason. Anything else I could try?

Comment: @Dmitri if you post the full html page I will check it out.  May not be until later but I would be glad to take a look.

Comment: thanks for the reply, I identified the problem, for some reason the 'top' property of jQuery .ui-dialog has a very high value and so the container opens up way off the page.